# Problem on finding number with more than 500 factors

Tags: javascript

well this is problem number 12 on projecteuler website:

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

```
 1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

and here's my code (I'm new to Javascript)

```
let num = 1;
let add= 1;
let divisors = [];

while (divisors.length < 500){
  divisors = []

  for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    if(num % i == 0){
      divisors.push(i);
    }
  }

  add ++;
  num += add;
}
console.log(num - add)
```

this code run fine when I change the while loop condition to 300 or less. 
and this code running on Intel i7 Q740 1.75GHz. 
when I try it nothing shows up on console and my question is that's because of my CPU and lack of power or my code has issue? I wait about 20 mins and still nothing as result.

Comment: Make sure you don't reach [the largest integer that can be safely represented using the floating point notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) used by JavaScript to represent the numbers. Beyond it, `i++` doesn't work and the loop becomes infinite.

Comment: @axiac should I wrap it in BigInt like BigInt(i) ?

Comment: What is `n` ? It seems it isn't defined

Comment: @JonasWilms sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Several issues: `n` should be `num` and `i <= n` can be `i <= Math.ceil(n / 2)`. Also what is `b`? Other than that your code looks fine! Using a large number library might be a good idea.

Comment: @BM thanks for the tip but why change `i <= num` to `i <= Math.ceil(num / 2)` ? I don't get this part

Comment: I think the trick here is with Maths, not JS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function Also you should use the sum formula of Gauss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: It does not change the result, but optimize the speed. A natural number larger than half of another natural number cannot be its divisor. Thus no need to test.

Comment: @BM Good point!

Comment: @JonasWilms I consider not use that formula but add to the previous number, same results but less code.

Comment: There might be an analytic divisor function, but nevertheless the approach to write a recursive algorithm instead is not usually wrong. It should work but might hit platform or language limitations. Thus the task might very well be designed so that no consumer hardware can be used to solve it this way, making an analytic approach necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not very efficient as @Vasil Dininski pointed out but you won't reach the max Integer you just have to wait a while for your program to calculate.

I would recommend to optimize your code e.g. by writing a simple function which returns your number of divisors for your current number.

This could look similar to this:

```
function numberOfDivisors(num) {
  var numOfDivisors = 0;
  var sqrtOfNum = Math.sqrt(num);

  for(var i = 1; i <= sqrtOfNum; i++) {
    if(num % i == 0) {
      numOfDivisors += 2;
    }
  }
  // if your number is a perfect square you have to reduce it by one
  if(sqrtOfNum * sqrtOfNum == num) {
    numOfDivisors--;
  }
  return numOfDivisors;
}
```

Then you could use this method in your while loop like this:

```
var maxNumOfDivisors = 500;
var num = 0;
var i = 1;

while(numberOfDivisors(num) < maxNumOfDivisors) {
  num += i;
  i++;
}
```

which would return you the correct triangular number.

Please also note that triangular numbers start at 0 which is why my num is 0.

Answer (score 1):

As you might have noticed, this algorithm might be a bit brute-force. A better one would be combine a few things. Let's assume the number we're looking for is "n":

1. Find all prime numbers in the range [1, square root of n]. You will
   be iterating over `n`, so the [sieve of
   eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
   will help in terms of efficiency (you can memoize primes you've already found)
2. Given that any number can be expressed as a prime number to some power, multiplied by a prime number to some power, etc. you can find all the combinations of those primes to a power, which are divisors of `n`.

This would be a more efficient, albeit a more complicated way to find them. You can take a look at this quora answer for more details: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-divisors-of-any-number

Answer (score -1):

If my calculation is not wrong, you add one more to each next divisor from previous divisor and you get final result.

```
let prev = 0;

for(let i=0; i < 500; i++) {
    prev = prev + i;
}
console.log("AA ", prev);
```

Comment: I think that's not gonna work, consider the question one more time :)